# Stored Procedures with JSTL's <sql:query> tag

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp, jstl

I've learned in school that you can execute a query on MySQL Databases with JSP and the JSTL-SQL tag library.
To do so I write:
    `<sql:query var="results" dataSource="${datasource}">
        SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='xy'
    </sql:query>`

Now I have to execute a stored procedure (`COUNT(*)`, `SUM(datafield)`, ...) on a MySQL InnoDB database.
Is there any way to do that and to read the result with sql tags?
BTW: I know that I could use `${results.rowCount}` for reading the number of data/records returned by the query-command. But I always obtain a limited number of records with one query command (`LIMIT a, n`) and want to count how many records there are in the database without having to read and save them all in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be just as easy to put the select statement in the JSTL query providing you with the results you need without the stored procedure, unless you need to use an sproc for some reason. This seems pretty straight forward. The key is to make sure you use the AS assignment in the query so you can reference the values you want to using JSTL.

```
<sql:query var="results" dataSource="${datasource}">
    SELECT COUNT(field) AS count, SUM(otherField) AS sum FROM table WHERE name='xy'
</sql:query>

<c:forEach items="${results.rows}" var="result">
    ${result.count} : ${result.sum}
</c:forEach>
```